Употребление прозвища
Есть такое предложение: «Ты меня недооцениваешь. Раньше я был известен как “дельфин на суше”, а потому я хочу, чтобы ты...»
Является ли в данном случае сочетание дельфин на суше прозвищем, если персонаж использует его один раз за весь текст и явно в качестве шутки (то есть по факту его так никто никогда не называл)?
Как в таком случае можно это оформить? Всё-таки прозвища, насколько мне известно, пишутся без кавычек и с большой буквы (хотя и с последним есть вопросы, ведь слова у нас два, так что не понимаю, писать надо оба с большой буквы или только одно).
Помогите, пожалуйста.

• Чуть-чуть теории

И с к л ю ч е н и е - п о д п р а в и л о. В именах персонажей, выраженных
предложно-падежным сочетанием или глагольным сочетанием, с прописной
буквы пишется только первое слово, например: Рике с хохолком, Кот в сапогах,
Кот в шляпе, Некто в сером, Петушок со шпорами; Двое из ларца, одинаковых
с лица; (лиса) Принеси огня.

• Немного логики
Говорящего никто и никогда так не называл, поэтому считаю, что оформление в виде цитаты здесь не подходит (то есть кавычки не нужны).
Персонаж позиционирует себя (пусть даже ради хохмы) в качестве этого самого Дельфина, и собеседник вправе считать названное имя прозвищем.
● Решение
Я бы написала без кавычек и только первое слово с прописной:
Раньше я был известен как Дельфин на суше...
• Примеры
Даже среди самых бедных рыбаков, которые продавали осьминогов за воротами рынка, он был известен как Мисуги-неудачник (Андрей Геласимов. Степные боги).
Еще в самом начале революционной карьеры, когда молодой Джугашвили (Сталин) был известен как Коба, Енукидзе учил его марксизму... (Александр Бармин. Двадцать лет в разведке).
Прописные и строчные буквы в собственных именах людей, прозвищах, псевдонимах, кличках: из академических правил русской орфографии (стр. 212)

Оставьте кавычки - чужие процитированные слова, а прописных не надо вовсе:
«Ты меня недооцениваешь. Раньше я был известен как “дельфин на суше”, а потому я хочу, чтобы ты...»

Я бы тоже так написала, никаких сомнений.
